# How to test IP Tables Rule (Linux Ubuntu12.04)

Tags: linux, iptables

I wanted to ask how to test IP Table Rules. For example, I have a port number and I want to be sure that it accepts all packets. How can I do it?

After I type `iptables -L` I see that the rule has been added but I need a practical proof.
Is there a way how I can do it?

I can't find online any resource about how to do that rather then to check the existence of the IP Table rule.

The rule which I wanted to test is:

```
sudo iptables –A INPUT –i eth0 –j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a copy of the rule you wish to test with a log option "above" the actual rule. Monitor the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu's IP is public on Internet, you could use [this tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/ping/ping.php) to ping the port you want to test.

Comment: is it it sufficient to test it just with ping command?

Comment: To test incoming TCP packets, yes.

Comment: What about UDP packets? Also what if I test it with `nmap -p <portNumber> <interface>` and I get that the port is filtered, is it considered that the port accepted the packed?